How does one use the adjective "überlegen"?
Wie kann man das Adjektiv überlegen nutzen? Ich möchte einen Satz formulieren, in dem es heißt: "Ich liebe dieses Brot, weil es eine bessere Textur hat als das andere.", aber ich möchte lieber nicht besser als verwenden.

How is the adjective überlegen used? I want to formulate a sentence that says: "I love this bread because the texture of it is better than the other.", but rather not use better than.

+1 @bakunins Antwort. Entweder ist die Haptik besser oder Du bist präziser. Dann ist die Textur oder der Teig bzw. die Kruste bspw. weicher, angenehmer, geschmeidiger, geschmacks-intensiver, krosser,... welche Eigenschaft auch immer sie konkret von anderen Broten unterscheidet, die sodass Du dieses eine als besser empfindest. Das Adverb "überlegen" in solchem Kontext wird die Herkunft des Satzes als zwar verständliche aber schlechte Übersetzung aus dem Englischen ausweisen

Please don't ask questions in both English or German; just pick the language you feel more comfortable in. The custom here is to answer the question in the language it was asked, so it's confusing when the question is asked in both languages.

@bakunin nein, wie hier geschrieben war von mir der upvote für deine nun gelöschte Antwort, nicht der downvote. Das habe ich auch nicht geändert als der Nachtrag auftauchte, weil eben nur Ergänzung

Das Adjektiv "überlegen" deutet m.E. eine Konkurrenz oder sogar einen Konflikt an; "überlegen sein" heißt dann "Eigenschaften haben, durch die man den Wettbewerb/Kampf gewinnt". Beim Geschmack eines Brotes kommt mir das übertrieben vor.
Verwendungsbeispiele und Definitionen findet man unter: https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%BCberlegen#2
"Ich mag dieses Brot weil ..." scheint mir ausreichend. "Textur" ist etwas fachsprachlich, "Beschaffenheit des Teigs" ("Weil der Teig ...(Adj) ist"), "Mundgefühl" und so passen vielleicht auch.

Ich stimme dir voll zu. Falls das mit dem Brot in der Frage nur ein Beispiel war, wäre eine Erläuterung, wie man überlegen verwendet, noch eine gute Ergänzung der ansonsten richtigen Antwort, auch für zukünftige Besucher:innen der Frage, denke ich :) Es ist immer nett, die Antwort direkt hier zu haben, und nicht nur in einem Link.

Solange es Teig ist, ist es kein Brot, und sobald es Brot ist, ist es kein Teig mehr.

So genau würde ich es nicht nehmen. Wer kennt schon das Wort "Krume"?

Also ich finde durchaus, dass ein handwerklich gebackenes Sauerteigbrot einem Brot aus dem Supermarkt in jeder Hinsicht überlegen ist (insbesondere geschmacklich).

Überlegen takes a dative complement as the thing that you compare to, like this:

Dieses Brot ist dem anderen (in | hinsichtlich | gemäß) der Textur überlegen.


Das Adjektiv "überlegen" braucht eine Konkurrenz oder einen Vergleich, der sichtbar oder messbar ist. Meist können die Sachen (oder Lebewesen) selbst in Aktion treten sodass diese in gewissen Sinne direkt gegeneinander wirken können. 'überlegen' hat eine viel engere Bedeutung als das Englische "Supreme" oder "superior".
Im Sport kann eine Mannschaft einer anderen überlegen sein.
Ein Produkt kann anderen Produkten seiner Kategorie technisch überlegen sein (weil es bspw. effizienter arbeitet oder länger hält etc - aber auch hier empfinde ich die Verwendung von 'überlegen' schon grenzwertig sinnvoll)
Es kann aber nicht eine Farbe einer anderen überlegen sein, da diese nie selber in Aktion tritt, Gleiches gilt für die Textur eines Brotes, allgemein bei Fragen des Geschmacks, der persönlichen Vorlieben etc. Bei solchen Vergleichen bietet es sich an, immer direkt die Eigenschaft zu vergleichen auf Grund derer man eine Sache als besser empfindet:
Brot A ist körniger / hat die krossere Kruste / hat die angenehmere Textur des Teiges / hat den nussigeren Geschmack / ... (und ist deshalb besser / leckerer ... als die Brote B und C).
